# How Do For loop to make short my statement

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I think it would be a simple question but I really stuck on it! how can I use for loop to make my statement more complex and short? I need the output be the exactly[image] same format
this is a code

```
courses_data = pd.read_csv('.........')

selected_features = ['course_name','course_link','university_name','course_type',
                     'university_logo', 'time_required', 'course_language', 
                     'course_subtitles', 'course_skills', 'course_rating', 
                     'category', 'sub_category', 'course_level']

combined_features = courses_data['course_name']+' '+courses_data['course_link']+' '+courses_data['university_name']+' '+courses_data['course_type']+' '+courses_data['university_logo']+' '+courses_data['time_required']+' '+courses_data['course_language']+' '+courses_data['course_subtitles']+' '+courses_data['course_skills']+' '+courses_data['course_rating']+' '+courses_data['category']+' '+courses_data['sub_category']+' '+courses_data['course_level']
print(combined_features)
```

Comment: You can use `.join()` and generator comprehension  `combined_features = ' '.join(courses_data[_] for _ in selected_features)`

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
combined_features = courses_data[selected_features[0]]
for feature in selected_features[1:]:
  combined_features += ' ' + courses_data[feature]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a pandas dataframe you could just do

```
df2 = courses_data[selected_features].copy()
print(df2)
```

OR

```
df2 = courses_data.filter(selected_features, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

[Source](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-create-new-dataframe-by-selecting-specific-columns/)

Comment: actually, I am trying to combine the feature_features I don't want to have the same data frame with selected features. but you are right if we would like to have a data frame with selected features it would be good idea

Answer (score 1):

```
combined_features = ""
selected_features = ['course_name','course_link','university_name','course_type',
                     'university_logo', 'time_required', 'course_language',
                     'course_subtitles', 'course_skills', 'course_rating',
                     'category', 'sub_category', 'course_level']

for feature in selected_features:
    combined_features += courses_data[feature] + " "

print(combined_features)
```

Comment: Brilliant! this code works for me thank you